# Deep link doesnt work from Firebase email verification link

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have setup a deep link in firebase console ,updates SHA1, SHA256 and I tried calling the deep link from mobile browser it perfectly opens installed app , but when I try using email verification link sent from app it goes to play store. Below is how verification link is being sent

```
val actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
            .setUrl("https://testapp.page.link?login=true")
            .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
            .setIOSBundleId("test.example.com")
            .setAndroidPackageName(
                    "test.example.com",
                    true, 
                    "12" )
            .build()


    mAuth!!.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("EmailVerification", "Email sent.")
                }
            }
```

My intent filter looks like below

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />



            <data
                android:host="testapp.page.link"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="testapp.page.link"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
```

I have whitelisted the domain , I repeat the link works from mobile browser but not from email. Any help appreciated greatly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
        .setUrl("https://testapp.page.link?login=true")
        .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
        .setIOSBundleId("test.example.com")
        .setAndroidPackageName(
                "test.example.com",
                true, 
                // Minimum android version of app.
                "12" )
        .build()
```

I think you are requiring version "12" of your app which is likely not installed on device. You can pass null for that field or the current version of your app.

Comment: thanks , yes that was the issues i messed up the version and didnt notice.